# gh-pages branch not displaying

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, python-sphinx

I am working on publishing a set of documentation online using GitHub Actions to deploy to GitHub pages. I first tested this by building a test repository and then making sure that I was able to build and deploy the documentation before adding all of the files to my main project.

**Goal:** I am trying to deploy these docs/host them on the project's GitHub pages.

I have two repos the [`testdocs`](https://github.com/eolesinski/doctesting) repo and the [`mainproject`](https://github.com/eolesinski/geostates) repo. Once I was sure that it was working correctly on the `testdocs` repo I just copied over the same code to the main project. Unfortunately, this did not work.

I have narrowed it down to the fact that in the `docstesting` repo, I have two branches, one for the `main` and another for `gh-pages`. I am able to select either one of these then in the GitHub pages tab under settings. The `main` repo only has the `main` branch and does not have a second branch. I think this might be causing the problem. What is confusing to me is 1) they are using the exact same code and 2) I thought this was supposed to be automatically deployed by the GitHub Action.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong here? Or, alternatively, perhaps an explanation as to why/how my main project is not getting a `gh-pages` branch?

The files of interest are the **docs** directory and the **sphinx.yml** file in the .github/workflows directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your [`.github/workflows/sphinx.yml`](https://github.com/eolesinski/geostates/blob/2688abaf7787f4b7d53d692e361040025644deeb/.github/workflows/sphinx.yml) uses [`peaceiris/actions-gh-pages`](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages) with:

```
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
```

It should deploy the `main` branch in both repositories.
Try and add " [Another GitHub Pages Branch](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#%EF%B8%8F-set-another-github-pages-branch-publish_branch)" set to `main`:

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
    github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    publish_branch: your-branch  # default: gh-pages  <======
```

[Ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12035742/ethan) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73642282/gh-pages-branch-not-displaying/73644420#comment130113996_73644420) an issue with branch name:

> Your answer drew my attention to the fact that I had set it to "`main`" but instead needed to set it to "`master`", as this is the branch that the original code was on.

Comment: @Ethan Indeed that is strange. Did you replace 'your-branch' by main in my example?

Comment: @Ethan What I understood from your question is that the second repository could only deploy from `main`, since it has no `gh-pages` branch. Is that correct?

Comment: I was able to solve it. Your answer drew my attention to the fact atet I had set it to "main" but instead needed to set it to "master" instead as this is the branch that the original code was on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ethan Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.